# C program that, after compiling and linking, results in an EXE file that contains an edata section?

Tags: c, compilation, executable, portable-executable

I am reviewing the Microsoft specification on Portable Executable files (EXE files). In particular, I am reviewing the .edata (export data) section. Here's [what the specification says about the edata section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format#the-edata-section-image-only):

> The export data section, named .edata, contains information about
>   symbols that other images can access through dynamic linking. Exported
>   symbols are generally found in DLLs, but DLLs can also import symbols.

Can a non-DLL file have an edata section? Specifically, can a C program, after compiling and linking, result in an EXE file that contains an edata section? If yes, would you show a simple C program that, after compiling and linking, results in an EXE file that contains an edata section, please?

Comment: at first section name not play any role at all. and any PE can have export table, in what is problem ?

Comment: *The export data section, named .edata* - this is wrong. `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` data directory not a section, can belong to any section with any name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any PE Image file may contain an export table, regardless of whether it is an EXE or DLL. However, the export tables are not necessarily contained within an `.edata` section. It is, for example, common to see export tables in the `.rdata` section instead.

To locate the export table, you should use the Export Table data directory, and not rely on the Section Table at all.

The following is an example C program that, when compiled, will produce an EXE with an export table. However, it might not be placed inside an `.edata` section (and the EXE might not have an `.edata` section at all).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void some_func(void)
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    return;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

---

When I compile this program using Visual Studio 2017 on my system, and run `dumpbin /HEADERS /EXPORTS` on the resulting EXE, I see the following:

```
...

SECTION HEADER #3
  .rdata name
    2A94 virtual size
   19000 virtual address (0000000140019000 to 000000014001BA93)
    2C00 size of raw data
    7E00 file pointer to raw data (00007E00 to 0000A9FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Only

...


  Section contains the following exports for SampleApp.exe

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 0001108C some_func = @ILT+135(some_func)
```

which confirms that the Export Table was put in the `.rdata` section in this case.

Comment: Thank you @Erlend Graff - awesome!